# Share a pdf to whatsapp number? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [printing 5.9.3](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) flutter package to preview html in pdf format.I want to share that pdf to spesific whatsapp number.How can i do that.

```
 Future<Uint8List> doc = Printing.convertHtml(
    format: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    html: htmlString
);



  sahreOnWhatsapp(String phoneNumber,Uint8List doc){
       //share doc to wahtsapp number
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [whatsapp_share2](https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp_share2) package like this:

```
sahreOnWhatsapp(String phoneNumber,Uint8List doc){
    final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    final docPath = await File('$directory/share.pdf').create();
    await docPath.writeAsBytes(doc);

    if (imagePath.path.isNotEmpty) {
      await WhatsappShare.shareFile(
         text: 'Whatsapp share text',
         phone: phoneNumber,
         filePath: [docPath.path],
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not null safe. I used https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp_share2 instead. Thank you.

Comment: It's great. glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`whatsapp_share`** package.

Link to [Documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp_share).